# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in string query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not familiar with Oracle syntax, but I am getting a missing right parenthesis error when I am passing this string to an .Net Oracle Command and then it tries to fill the data adapter.

```
 string cT = "SELECT 'PRODUCT' AS ItemType, 'x' || CAST(LPROD.QUANTITY AS VARCHAR2(50)), " +
                  "PNAME.NAME || ' (' || CAST((PRODS.\"SIZE\" AS VARCHAR2(50))) || ' ' || PRODS.MEASURE || ')' AS Name, " +
                  "PRODS.PRODUCT_ID as ProductSizeID, PRODS.UPC_CODE as BarCode FROM ORDERS ORDR, LI_PROD LPROD, PRODUCT_NAME PNAME, " +
                  "PRODUCT PRODS WHERE ORDR.INV_NUM = :Invoice_Num AND ORDR.ORDER_NUM = LPROD.ORDER_NUM " +
                  "AND LPROD.PRODUCT_ID = PRODS.PRODUCT_ID AND PRODS.PRODUCT_NAME_ID = PNAME.ID";
```

Can anyone spot the error that may be causing this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I count 11 parens.  You should always have an even number.  Ar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cast(prods."SIZE" as varchar2(50))
```

Instead of:

```
cast((prods."SIZE" as varchar2(50)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up with the exact same issue and could not find a solution. What ended up happening was that I had the following code from SQLServer that I was attempting to convert to Oracle.

```
CAST(col AS NVARCHAR(250)) AS col_name,
```

I was able to fix it by changing it to

```
CAST(col AS NVARCHAR2(250)) AS col_name,
```